# Magento : Error in creating new attribute set

Tags: magento-1.9, attribute-set

I've having issue when creating a new attribute set based on the existing one.

When you try to do this, it creates the new set but fails to bring over the attributes - it’s as if you simply created a blank set.

I'm trying hard looking into many database tables and class but can't find the actual problem.

any one has any experience in this issue, Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Create new product attribute set script**

```
$newSetName = 'Apple';
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$attributeSetID = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
$installer->startSetup();
$entityTypeId = (int) $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');

$attributeSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
    ->setEntityTypeId($entityTypeId)
    ->setAttributeSetName($newSetName);

if ($attributeSet->validate()) {
     $attributeSet->save()
     ->initFromSkeleton($attributeSetID)
     ->save();
}
else {
    die('Attributeset with name ' . $newSetName . ' already exists.');
}

$installer->endSetup();
```